# How can I convert an edge loop to a curve?

Tags: bezier-curves, edges

I saw a cryengine video in which an edge loop is dragged to adjust it just like the ones in paint. I am not sure if that feature is available in Blender. If yes, would greatly help in modelling objects like bridges, arches etc. The link to the video: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=0X123xPlyWM the curve is used in 00:18 of the video.

Comment: As well as the answers here, you might want to look at the Loop Tools add-on, Curve option. But I think its usefulness is pretty restricted.

Comment: You can create a curve and adjust it with Blender possibilties, then cut the main mesh with that curve by using Knife Project

Answer (score 14):

Anyone who lands here from a search engine, in Blender 2.8, Alt + C doesn't do anything. `Curve from Mesh` is not even available in the space bar menu. You have to select it from `Object` > `Convert to` menu.

Comment: I can confirm this.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. The devs have unilaterally ruined all of the knowledge base without a deprecation cycle or allowing for alternative uses. Most of the tutorials on the internet do not work any more, and the documentation is too dry to get anything done. It is terrible.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, blender doesn't have a magic button that can do this so you have to do it manually.

1. Select the edge loop and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> to put it back
2. Press <kbd>P</kbd>, seperate by selection
3. Select the new mesh and in object mode, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and choose Curve from Mesh/Text

Comment: I don't use a keyboard, so what is Alt+C?

Comment: Anyone who lands here, this is the correct answer, but in Blender 2.8, Alt + C doesn't do anything. `Curve from Mesh` is not even available in the spacebar menu. You have to select it from `Object` > `Convert to` menu.

Comment: @dotNET - I would almost go as far as suggest you move this comment into an answer in it's own right. Almost every link I followed when looking for "edge-to-curve" resulted in the alt+C method which is useless in blender 2.8+. This is the only suggestion I've found that works. Thank you and consider moving to answer. I for one, will upvote immediately to help spread the new "correct" method.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett: Thanks. Done.

Comment: It's so dumb that they remove this command from the search bar

Comment: @ChristianWilliam Does anyone know why it was removed? It feels like an oversight, as it's a very practical command, especially when we're dealing with things like clothing patterns.

Answer (score 2):

The nearest to that functionality would be Proportional Edit - simply select the edge loop in the middle of the structure (rather than the edge), enable Proportional Edit, use Grab (<kbd>G</kbd>) and adjust the radius (middle mouse wheel).

[image: proportional edit]